# Why can't ghci match this type?

Tags: haskell

I'm working through the [following Haskell book](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) - looking at the Chapter [Walk the Line](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#walk-the-line):

When I run the following code in ghci:

```
type Birds = Int  
type Pole = (Birds,Birds)  

x -: f = f x

:{
landLeft :: Birds -> Pole -> Maybe Pole
landLeft n (left,right)
    | abs ((left + n) - right) < 4 = Just (left + n, right)
    | otherwise                    = Nothing
:}

:{
landRight :: Birds -> Pole -> Maybe Pole
landRight n (left,right)
    | abs (left - (right + n)) < 4 = Just (left, right + n)
    | otherwise                    = Nothing
:}

--Failure
(0,0) -: landLeft 1 -: landRight 4 
--(0,0) -: landLeft 1 -: landRight 4 -: landLeft (-1) -: landRight (-2)  
--(0,2)
```

I get the error:

```
Prelude> (0,0) -: landLeft 1 -: landRight 4 

<interactive>:17:24: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Maybe Pole’ with ‘(Birds, Birds)’
      Expected type: Maybe Pole -> Maybe Pole
        Actual type: Pole -> Maybe Pole
    • In the second argument of ‘(-:)’, namely ‘landRight 4’
      In the expression: (0, 0) -: landLeft 1 -: landRight 4
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = (0, 0) -: landLeft 1 -: landRight 4
```

My question is: **Why can't ghci match this type?**

Comment: `Maybe Pole` is not `Pole`. You can't pass a `Maybe Pole` to something that takes a `Pole`. LYAH is going to go into this soon.

Comment: Thanks @AJFarmar - that helpful. Could you expand that in terms of how this can be resolved?

Comment: LYAH is going to tell you how to do this, but you could write `a :- f = a >>= f` and write `Just (0,0)` instead of `(0,0)`. But once again, LYAH is going to explain this soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variants of `landLeft` and `landRight` that work with `-:` use `Pole` as return type, not `Maybe Pole`. Let's view all types at ones:

```
landLeft  1             ::       Pole -> Maybe Pole
landRight 4             ::       Pole -> Maybe Pole 
(-:)                    :: a -> (a    -> b         ) -> b
(0,0)                   :: Pole
(-:) (0,0)              ::      (Pole -> b         ) -> b
(-:) (0,0) (landLeft 1) ::                              Maybe Pole
```

Since `Maybe Pole` isn't `Pole`, we cannot use `(-:)` again for `landRight`. LYAH shows how to deal with those functions: you need a way to use `a -> Maybe b` functions with `Maybe a`. That's `(>>=)` job:

```
landLeft 1 (0,0) >>= landRight 4
```

Continue the chapter, as the author immediately tackles your issue:

> When we land birds without throwing Pierre off balance, we get a new pole wrapped in a `Just`. But when many more birds end up on one side of the pole, we get a `Nothing`. This is cool, but ***we seem to have lost the ability to repeatedly land birds on the pole***. We can't do `landLeft 1 (landRight 1 (0,0))` anymore because when we apply `landRight 1` to `(0,0)`, we don't get a `Pole`, but a `Maybe Pole`. `landLeft 1` takes a `Pole` and not a `Maybe Pole`. [emphasis mine]

Comment: Thanks @Zeta that’s helpful. Are you saying that where the book says that the erroring code gives a valid value - that the book contains a typo?

Comment: @hawkeye I'm saying that the chapter has to be read completely in sequence. If you read only the snippets, you can end up with broken code. There are _two_ variants of `landLeft`, one that uses `Maybe` and is therefore unsuitable for `(-:)`, and one that does not use `Maybe` and is therefore suitable for `(-:)`. It's unfortunate that both variants share the same name.